# scala Map to Seq and map() suddenly fails with no errors

Tags: scala

I have the following piece of code. Something suspicious is happening here.

```
/* 1. */ case class DBCurrencyRate(currency: String, dateTime: Timestamp, rateToEuro: Double)
/* 2. */ val rates: Map[String, Double] = ...
/* 3. */ val seqRates = rates.toSeq.map(rate =>
/* 4. */  DBCurrencyRate(rate._1, new Timestamp(date.toInstant.toEpochMilli), rate._2)
/* 5. */ )
/* 6. */ val action = DBIO.seq(seqRates)
```

On the first line I am declaring my case class. The timestamp is `java.sql.Timestamp`.

On the second line I declare a map with rates.

On the third line I transform my map to a sequence on which I apply a map.

Now if I put a breakpoint on the 4-th and the 6-th lines, it will reach that breakpoint on the 4-th line. If I try to go to the next line in debugger or even skip (execute) until my next breakpoint on the 6-th line, the execution suddenly goes somewhere. I do not know where, it doesn't show anything. No expections or other errors appear in the log.

If I replace `rates.seq......` with `DBIO.seq(DBCurrencyRate("EUR", new Timestamp(date.toInstant.toEpochMilli), 2.42))` it will work.

Comment: Debugger bug? This doesn't look like a scala question, more like a bug report for the particular debugger you are using.

Comment: It's the IntelliJ debugger. I don't think the debugger is the issue because even without the debugger it still does't insert row in DB.

Comment: Well, it certainly doesn't just "go into nowhere" without the debugger, does it ? :) 
Insert some print statements. A try/catch maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Dima's suggestion I used a try-catch and it captured an `UnsupportedOperationException` when creating the `Timestamp`. The problem was that I was sending a very small `Int` to the `Timestamp`.